# Sum is not a function in jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I started to write some tests today for my first time with Jest and Enzyme.
It worked fine until I wanted to test a specific function, "sum".

The error i got was: *TypeError: (0 , _App.sum) is not a function*
What can cause this?

Here's my App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'

const App = () => {
    const sum = (a, b) => {
        return a + b
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <p>Hello</p>
                <a
                    className="App-link"
                    href="https://reactjs.org"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                    Learn React
                </a>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

My App.test.js file:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import App from './App'
import { sum } from './App'

it('renders without crashing', () => {
    shallow(<App />)
})

it('Text contains Hello', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />)
    expect(wrapper.contains(<p>Hello</p>)).toEqual(true)
})

it('Sum equals 3', () => {
    expect(sum(2 + 1)).toBe(3) // This one fails, why?
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Sum is not exported from your file:

```
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'

export const sum = (a, b) => {
    return a + b
}

const App = () => {
    

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <p>Hello</p>
                <a
                    className="App-link"
                    href="https://reactjs.org"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                    Learn React
                </a>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: That wont work because the function in outside of my component, I want it inside

Comment: @gospecomid12 You can't test this function from inside your component, your should either test it in isolation, or use it in your component, simulate interaction with your component and test the result